# `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers` when using istio-ingress-gateway

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, istio-gateway

I was testing my ingress and I deleted the following two gateways for testing purpose.

```
kubectl delete gateway istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress -n istio-system
kubectl delete gateway istio-system-gateway -n istio-system
```

Since, then I am having this error `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers` for any url I access through the `ingress-gateway`.

Is it related and if so, how can I set them up again?
If not, how can I debug this?

I have tried to reinstall istio following this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio.
However, it did not work nor did the two gateways got recreatted.

Answer (score 1):

as noted [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/4999#issuecomment-399472054), you should check your namespace is correctly labeled with istio-injection=enabled

```
kubectl describe ns <your namespace>
```

if not, add the correct label :

```
kubectl label namespace <your namespace> istio-injection=enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this by looking at the istio-ingressgateway container logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always reinstall the same Istio release by following the `kubectl apply -f [...]` step of the Istio release files as listed in the tutorial. This should restore those deleted system objects.

**Sidenote:** never, ever, delete stuff from a namespace named `*-system`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably there is mismatch of the port that application running in the DOCKER is not the same port exposed in the DOCKER configuration

Docker file `EXPOSE <PORT>` should be same as the port the application is started.

Istio Ingress gateway can bind to the container port but not communicate the application.